# preventDefault() does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Can anyone point out what is wrong with this code. This works in chrome but not in Firefox. I have updated my question to be more clear. Please have a look at the look below.Actaully, it is tinymce editor.When I click,the equation symbol in the toolbar,a span with class AMedit is automatically created.Now when the cursor is inside the equation,the enter key should not move the cursor to new line.My code works only in chrome but not in other browsers.You can check this in different browsers.

http://beyondthelogix.com/demos/editordemo/demo.html

```
tinyMCE.init({

theme : "advanced",
mode: "exact",
elements : "elm1",
setup : function(ed) {
ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
    tinymce.dom.Event.add(ed.getDoc(), 'keydown', function(e) {
        var existing = tinyMCE.get('elm1').getElement(e);
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        var spans = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().getElementsByTagName("span");
        if (spans.length > 0)
        {
           for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
           {
              if (spans[i].getAttribute("class") === "AMedit")
              {
                 if (code === 13)
                 {

        (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
         }
              }
           }
        }
    });
  });
},
```

When I use alert, I get it in firefox but `e.preventDefault()` does not work.

Comment: Which version of tinymce do you use? Is there an error message in the console?

Comment: tinymce 3.4.4. There is no error message in the console.

Comment: If I remember right, FireFox is  still  tirggering a `keypress` event even if you prevent the `keydown`. I think listening to `keypress` instead `keydown` will already solve your problem - but I currently can't test it myself to confirm it.

Comment: I have used keypress,keyup,keydown. Same problem, works only in chrome.

Comment: I believe it works by adding "event.stopPropagation ()"

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Chrome initializes the `event` but Firefox doesn't.
Use this and it will work in Firefox and Chrome.

Don't put 100 `preventDefault();`. Put where is needed.

Example:

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).fadeOut(250, function () {
        $(this).closest('td').children('.hiddenDiv').show().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This: `(e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;` 
it seems you are trying to access a property `preventDefault` instead of call method `preventDefault()`

Answer (score -2):

try to return false instead, should work on all the browsers.

```
return false;
```

Comment: Sorry I have already used that.It does not work.Thanks for reply

Comment: `return false;` is a convention which jQuery uses. It is not valid for DOM events.

Comment: i'm not sure that the issue with preventDefault, it looks like you did something wrong or there is  a bug with tinyMCE.

Comment: If there is bug in my code or in tinymce, then why it works in chrome but not in firefox ??

Comment: @HaralanDobrev, Not completely true, `return false` works for the DOM0 event model, such as `el.onclick = ...`.

Answer (score -2):

try tu use evt instead of e to use the preventDEfault.

```
evt.preventDefault()
```

I think you are calling a variable or aprameter that doesn't exists. Doy you see anything in the console?

Comment: `evt`  is the event of the init callback in that case, not of the key event.

Comment: e is for event not a variable.It works well in chrome but not in Firefox and there is no error in the console